# php: slack or email notifications sending

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller called Guzzle controller.Yurrently, I am  passing the slack class as a dependency through the constructor, but iam not using it. Instead i am  using the Slack class as static (`Slack::send(...blablabla`).

```
const DEFAULT_FREQUENCY = 1;

private $client;
private $Slack;

public function __construct(Client $clinet,Slack $slack)
{
    $this->client = $clinet;
    $this->slack = $slack;
}

public function status()
{
    $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();
    $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
    }
}

private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
{
    $status_health = $notification->status('health');

    $frequency = $this->getFrequency($notification);

    $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

    if ($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {
        $response = $this->client->get($notification->website_url, ['http_errors' => false]);   
        $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values'=> $response->getStatusCode() === 200 ? 'up' : 'down'
            ]);
        $resCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        if($resCode != 200){
            Slack::send('the site is dying help!!');
        }
    }

}

private function getFrequency(Notification $notification)
{
    return isset($notification->check_frequency) 
    ? intval($notification->check_frequency) 
    : self::DEFAULT_FREQUENCY;
}
```

}
now iam trying to accomplish the following task
1, But GuzzleController class shouldn't be depending on Slack. But it should depend on another class. Let's call it `Reporter` and its job would be to report to certain channels when needed?

Comment: Please stop false tagging your questions, this has nothing to do with CakePHP - thanks.

Comment: what is going on?

Comment: What is the question

Comment: the question is to create a class responsible for sending notifications either slack or email notification. i want to create that class and this controller should depend on it ?

Comment: depending on the http response from this class, another class should be able to send a notification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below approach to send Slack/Email notifications..

Create a folder with the name `Utilities` inside `app`. Now create a class with `Reporter.php` as follows

namespace App\Utilities;

use Slack;
use Mail;

```
class Reporter
{
  public function slack($message,$slack_channel)
  {
     /*  Slack::to($slackChannel)->send($message);*/
    Slack::to($slack_channel)->send($message);


  }

  public function mail($emails, $message)
  {

    Mail::queue('emails.notification', ['message' => $message], function($m) use ($emails) {
      $m->to($emails);
      $m->subject('Notification....');
    });
  }
}
```

Now instead of using the name `GuzzleController`, use something like `NotificationController` because the controller is majorly used for sending notifications and not just checking site status via **Guzzle**...

So, rename `GuzzleController.php` to `NotificationController.php` and replace its contents with

```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use App\Utilities\Reporter;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

    class NotificationController
    {
      const DEFAULT_FREQUENCY = 1;

      protected $client;
      protected $reporter;

      public function __construct()
      {
        $this->client = new Client;

        $this->reporter = new Reporter;
      }

      public function status()
      {
        $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
          $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        }
      }

      private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
      {
        $status_health = $notification->status('health');

        $frequency = $this->getFrequency($notification);

        $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

        if($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {
          $response = $this->client->get($notification->website_url, [
            'http_errors' => false
          ]);   

          $resCode = $response->getStatusCode();

          $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values' => $resCode === 200 ? 'up' : 'down'
          ]);

          if($resCode != 200){
            $this->reporter->slack('the site is dying help!!');

            // And if you also want to send email
            // $this->reporter->mail($userEmail, 'the site is dying help!!');
          }
        }

      }

      private function getFrequency(Notification $notification)
      {
        return isset($notification->check_frequency) 
        ? intval($notification->check_frequency) 
        : self::DEFAULT_FREQUENCY;
      }
    }
```

Basically, as asked by you, you have a **separate class (Reporter) to send Slack/Mail notifications** and **separate class to for updating Statuses and sending Notifications** based on frequency etc...

Hope I understood your question well, let me know if you face any other issues by commenting below :)

Comment: You have done great work.  You understood my question and gave me what I need! There is  only one issue though, it fetches all the URLs in the database and able to send http request, but if for instance number 2 website is down, it sends slack and email notification but failed to check the nect url. it only send slack and e mail notification only to the first failed one and stop to check the next?

Comment: @abrahamfoto Unsure if you are asking me that it will send all the sites or you want me to stop this if any of the websites is down. According to the code, it should check all websites and not just one and send slack notification if either of them are down... Even for next URL. Please keep in mind that the the slack notification part will only take place if `$elapsed_time >= $frequency`.

Comment: what i wanted is, it has to check all websites and in case one or more are failed, it send notifications. But now i have to fake websites, they are both not in online. it is sending notification only for the first one not for the second one. i wanted it to send notifications, no matter how many websites are dawn. but currently, even though $elapsed_time >= $frequency is true for both websites, it only send notification for the first one.

Comment: This code should work for all websites.... I am unsure what is really happening on your end but there is no break in the `foreach()` loop. Can you try and check what **statusCode** you are getting for both sites individually.